# How to handle browser warning for SSL certificate

Tags: tomcat, browser, ssl, ssl-certificate

For the development we are using a self signed SSL certificate and it seems to work fine except one issue that for the first time when user click the URL browser will show the warning  about certificate is not valid and we can easily bypass it by telling browser that we trust this site.

i have a use case where i need to load some data in Iframe and that data needs to be picked using HTTPS and the process is hidden and that Iframe is only visible when user click on a certain link.
my problem is for the user who is visiting that site for the first time, when click on that link is getting browser error message.

is there any way to let browser trust our self signed certificate and not showing warning message?

Comment: If you **have to** use self-signed certificates, you have to send each generated certificate to each user and tell them to install them in browser.

Comment: seems like that is the only option till we get one from trusted CA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only two options are to tell the user to configure their browser to accept certificates signed by your organization, or to get the certificate signed by some CA browsers trust.

Answer (score 7):

These days there is really no reason to use a self-signed certificate and then try to figure out how to suppress client warnings. Instead, go to http://www.startssl.com/ and get yourself a free certificate that is recognized by all reasonably recent web browsers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startssl#Trustedness). Getting signed-into their website is a bit of a hassle (they require you to download a client-certificate and install it into your browser before you can request a server certificate) but then you can get free, trusted SSL certificates for your websites.